# Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In the below sql statement i get the following error

> Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the
>   group by list of a GROUP BY clause.

How can i get around this?

```
SELECT
    T.Post,
    COUNT(*) AS ClientCount,
    Client = CASE COUNT(*) WHEN '1' THEN T.Client ELSE '[Clients]' END
FROM
    MyTable T
GROUP BY
    T.Post,
    CASE COUNT(*) WHEN '1' THEN T.Client ELSE '[Clients]' END
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unless you include `T.Client` in your `GROUP BY`, you can only include that field within an aggregate function.  In your case, grouping by that field changes the logic, so that's out (and is related to your attempt to group by the CASE statement).  Instead, wrap `T.Client` in an aggregate function.

This way your groups are still the same, and when there is only one row, as per your CASE statement's test, you know what result the aggregate funciton is going to give.

```
SELECT
  T.Post,
  ClientCount = COUNT(*) AS ClientCount,
  Client      = CASE COUNT(*) WHEN 1 THEN MAX(T.Client) ELSE '[Clients]' END
FROM
  MyTable T
GROUP BY
  T.Post
```

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to group by that CASE expression.

```
SELECT
    T.Post,
    COUNT(*) AS ClientCount,
    CASE COUNT(*) WHEN '1' THEN MIN(T.Client) ELSE '[Clients]' END Client
FROM
    MyTable T
GROUP BY
    T.Post
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the reference to `T.Client` will not be valid here due to it not being part of the grouping. He'll probably need to define that column via a correlated sub-query.

Comment: @Daniel You are right. I did not pay attention to that part. Fixed.