# Cant resolve "Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause" ERROR

Tags: sql

Some answers to this error suggest that I cannot use dm.DonarName without a aggregate function, but not sure how can I do it in this specific case?

Looking at another solution ([Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873646/cannot-use-an-aggregate-or-a-subquery-in-an-expression-used-for-the-group-by-lis)), I tried using MAX (dm.DonorMasterId) instead of dm.DonarNamer and it still wouldn't work.

```
select      STUFF(( SELECT ','+ dm.DonarName
                FROM    dbo.DonarMaster dm
                JOIN dbo.PMFunder pmf on pmf.FunderId = dm.DonarMasterID
                WHERE   pmf.ProgramMasterID = pm.ProgramMasterID
                GROUP BY dm.DonarName
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(max)'), 1, 1, '') as "Funder"

    ,plgm.ProgramLaunchID 
    ,sm_tmo.FirstName + ' ' + sm_tmo.LastName as "TMO"  
    ,d.DistrictName as "Location"
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), pl.StartDate, 107) as "Project start date"
    ,COUNT (distinct plgm.GroupID) as "Target groups"
    ,SUM(case when plgm.ActivationDate IS NULL then 0 else 1 end) as "Active groups"
    ,COUNT (distinct plgm.GroupID) * plsm.TotalNosesssion as "Target (year)"
    ,'-' as "Target (YTD)"
    ,COUNT (a.TMOID) as "Actual"        

from    dbo.PLGroupMapping plgm
    ,dbo.ProgramLaunch pl
    ,dbo.ProgramMaster pm
    ,dbo.PMFunder pmf
    ,dbo.DonarMaster dm 
    ,dbo.District d
    ,Magicbus.dbo.PLSessionMapping plsm 
    ,dbo.StaffMaster sm_tmo
    LEFT JOIN #r6a a
    on a.TMOID = sm_tmo.StaffMasterID

where       plgm.ProgramLaunchid = pl.ProgramLaunchID
and         pl.ProgramMasterID = pm.ProgramMasterID
and         pm.ProgramMasterID = pmf.ProgramMasterID
and         pmf.FunderId = dm.DonarMasterID
and         plgm.TMOID = sm_tmo.StaffMasterID
and         pl.DistrictID = d.DistrictID
and         plsm.ProgramLaunchID = plgm.ProgramLaunchID

group by    STUFF(( SELECT ','+ dm.DonarName
                FROM    dbo.DonarMaster dm
                JOIN dbo.PMFunder pmf on pmf.FunderId = dm.DonarMasterID
                WHERE   pmf.ProgramMasterID = pm.ProgramMasterID
                GROUP BY dm.DonarName
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(max)'), 1, 1, '') 
        ,plgm.ProgramLaunchID
        ,sm_tmo.FirstName + ' ' + sm_tmo.LastName
        ,d.DistrictName
        ,pl.StartDate
        ,plsm.TotalNosesssion
order by    COUNT (a.TMOID), plgm.ProgramLaunchID
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @marc_s totally agree. I am editing someone else's code and will do all these changes as well once I see the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and quick fix is to use an aggregate function:

```
select      MAX(STUFF(( SELECT distinct ','+ dm.DonarName
                FROM    dbo.DonarMaster dm
                JOIN dbo.PMFunder pmf on pmf.FunderId = dm.DonarMasterID
                WHERE   pmf.ProgramMasterID = pm.ProgramMasterID
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(max)'), 1, 1, '') ) as "Funder"
    ,plgm.ProgramLaunchID 
    ,sm_tmo.FirstName + ' ' + sm_tmo.LastName as "TMO"  
    ,d.DistrictName as "Location"
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), pl.StartDate, 107) as "Project start date"
    ,COUNT (distinct plgm.GroupID) as "Target groups"
    ,SUM(case when plgm.ActivationDate IS NULL then 0 else 1 end) as "Active groups"
    ,COUNT (distinct plgm.GroupID) * plsm.TotalNosesssion as "Target (year)"
    ,'-' as "Target (YTD)"
    ,COUNT (a.TMOID) as "Actual"        

from    dbo.PLGroupMapping plgm
    ,dbo.ProgramLaunch pl
    ,dbo.ProgramMaster pm
    ,dbo.PMFunder pmf
    ,dbo.DonarMaster dm 
    ,dbo.District d
    ,Magicbus.dbo.PLSessionMapping plsm 
    ,dbo.StaffMaster sm_tmo
    LEFT JOIN #r6a a
    on a.TMOID = sm_tmo.StaffMasterID

where       plgm.ProgramLaunchid = pl.ProgramLaunchID
and         pl.ProgramMasterID = pm.ProgramMasterID
and         pm.ProgramMasterID = pmf.ProgramMasterID
and         pmf.FunderId = dm.DonarMasterID
and         plgm.TMOID = sm_tmo.StaffMasterID
and         pl.DistrictID = d.DistrictID
and         plsm.ProgramLaunchID = plgm.ProgramLaunchID

group by    
        plgm.ProgramLaunchID
        ,sm_tmo.FirstName + ' ' + sm_tmo.LastName
        ,d.DistrictName
        ,pl.StartDate
        ,plsm.TotalNosesssion
order by    COUNT (a.TMOID), plgm.ProgramLaunchID
```

The better way in my opinion is to move the correlated subquery to the LEFT JOIN, like this:

```
select   aa.Funder
    ,plgm.ProgramLaunchID 
    ,sm_tmo.FirstName + ' ' + sm_tmo.LastName as "TMO"  
    ,d.DistrictName as "Location"
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), pl.StartDate, 107) as "Project start date"
    ,COUNT (distinct plgm.GroupID) as "Target groups"
    ,SUM(case when plgm.ActivationDate IS NULL then 0 else 1 end) as "Active groups"
    ,COUNT (distinct plgm.GroupID) * plsm.TotalNosesssion as "Target (year)"
    ,'-' as "Target (YTD)"
    ,COUNT (a.TMOID) as "Actual"        

from    dbo.PLGroupMapping plgm
    ,dbo.ProgramLaunch pl
    ,dbo.ProgramMaster pm
     LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT pmf2.ProgramMasterID, STUFF(( SELECT distinct ','+ dm.DonarName
                FROM    dbo.DonarMaster dm
                JOIN dbo.PMFunder pmf on pmf.FunderId = dm.DonarMasterID
                WHERE   pmf.ProgramMasterID = pfm2.ProgramMasterID
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(max)'), 1, 1, '') as Funder
  FROM dbo.PMFunder pmf2 
  GROUP BY pmf2.ProgramMasterID
) aa ON aa.ProgramMasterID = pm.ProgramMasterID
    ,dbo.PMFunder pmf
    ,dbo.DonarMaster dm 
    ,dbo.District d
    ,Magicbus.dbo.PLSessionMapping plsm 
    ,dbo.StaffMaster sm_tmo
    LEFT JOIN #r6a a
    on a.TMOID = sm_tmo.StaffMasterID

where       plgm.ProgramLaunchid = pl.ProgramLaunchID
and         pl.ProgramMasterID = pm.ProgramMasterID
and         pm.ProgramMasterID = pmf.ProgramMasterID
and         pmf.FunderId = dm.DonarMasterID
and         plgm.TMOID = sm_tmo.StaffMasterID
and         pl.DistrictID = d.DistrictID
and         plsm.ProgramLaunchID = plgm.ProgramLaunchID

group by aa.Funder
        ,plgm.ProgramLaunchID
        ,sm_tmo.FirstName + ' ' + sm_tmo.LastName
        ,d.DistrictName
        ,pl.StartDate
        ,plsm.TotalNosesssion
order by    COUNT (a.TMOID), plgm.ProgramLaunchID
```

Comment: for the first query, I am getting this - _Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery._

Comment: try now. I removed the group by from the subquery and replaced it with a distinct